# Using cloudfront to handle static files and backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single page application (made with angular), which I am serving by pointing cloudfront to an S3 bucket. This is working well.

However, I want to run the backend of my website via the same domain - What I've done is added another origin to my cloudfront distribution which points to elastic beanstalk where the django app is running.

Then, I configured behaviors so that the Path Pattern /apiv1/* is handled by django. This doesn't work and I'm getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to access my endpoints.

The behavior I'm looking for is as follows:

1. / should point to index.html and load static files (this currently works)
2. /apiv1/... should point to django. For example, to access a login endpoint I would have website.come/apiv1/api/login (as a pose to localhost/api/login on my machine).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is doing something similar, here is a fix:

Add a subdomain - I added api.example.com which is a subdomain of example.com

Then, in Route 53, I configured api.example.com to point to elb via an alias and requested an ssl certificate for the subdomain! Note, YOU MUST use https when making requests hence the reason for the ssl certificate.

I simply changed the base url in my angular http requests and it works.